# python3: zip the values of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to zip the values of a dictionary like this:

```
j={'front': [3, 103, 173], 'back': [69, 139, 209]}
```

which would end up being a list of tuples like this:

```
[(3, 69), (103, 139), ...]
```

When I try doing this, I end up with a list of lists after converting the result of j.values() to a list.  Then I try zipping this, and I get the wrong result.

```
>>> j={'front': [3, 103, 173], 'back': [69, 139, 209]}
>>> j.values()
dict_values([[3, 103, 173], [69, 139, 209]])
>>> list(zip(j.values()))
[([3, 103, 173],), ([69, 139, 209],)]
```

Why am I not getting what I expect, and how to do fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `*` to your `.values()` call to unpack into `zip`.

```
>>> [tuple(i) for i in zip(*j.values())]
[(3, 69), (103, 139), (173, 209)]
```

which more succinctly is just

```
>>> list(zip(*j.values()))
[(3, 69), (103, 139), (173, 209)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
list(zip(*j.values()))
```

output:

```
[(3, 69), (103, 139), (173, 209)]
```